# Python List of dictionaries with tuples as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
Counter({('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'i'): 847, ('il', 'i'): 784, 
         ('want', 'to'): 680, ('want', 'you'): 561, ('il', 'you'): 561, 
         ('come', 'on'): 557, ('know', 't'): 499, ('go', 'to'): 447, 
         ('right', 'all'): 440, ('want', 'i'): 430, ('know', 'don'): 410, 
         ('get', 'to'): 409, ('like', 'you'): 397, ('like', 'i'): 338, 
         ('get', 'you'): 336, ('il', 'be'): 330})
```

And I want to create a list of dictionaries, where in each dictionary are only the tuples with the same first element, something like this

```
[{('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'i'): 847, ('know', 't'): 499,('know', 'don'): 410}, 
 {('want', 'to'): 680, ('want', 'you'): 561, ('want', 'i'): 430},  
 {('get', 'to'): 409, ('get', 'you'): 336}, 
 {('like', 'you'): 397, ('like', 'i'): 338}]
```

After that I want to store the values from each dictionary in the nested list and create an array. Nested list will look like that

```
[[1053, 847, 499, 410], [680, 561, 430], [409, 336], [397, 338]]
```

Do you have some ideas how can I do that?

EDIT: After some comments I realised that also the second element in the tuple has to correspond to other elements. So the list of dictionaries should look actually like this:

```
[{('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'i'): 847, ('know', 'to'): 499}
 {('want', 'you'): 5, ('want', 'i'): 430},  ('want', 'to'): 680}
 {('get', 'you'): 3, ('get', ‚i'): 68, ('get', 'to'): 409}
 {('like', 'you'): 397, ('like', 'i'): 338}, ('like', 'to'): 345}]
```

Comment: what is your problem? where is your code? what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to have the intermediate list of dictionaries? you can achieve your goal directly from your input dictionary pretty easily.

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in input_dict.items():
    out[k[0]].append(v)

print(out)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'know': [1053, 847, 499, 410], 'il': [784, 561, 330], 
#                              'want': [680, 561, 430], 'come': [557], 'go': [447],
#             '                'right': [440], 'get': [409, 336], 'like': [397, 338]})
```

then, if you insist on the nested lists:

```
print([v for v in out.values()])
# [[1053, 847, 499, 410], [784, 561, 330], [680, 561, 430], [557], [447], [440],
#  [409, 336], [397, 338]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new in Python, I tried one day to do that, but it is really very easy! :-)

Comment: Could it also be possible that we have corresponding second elements in each dictionary like this: 
[{('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'i'): 847, ('know', 'to'): 499}, 
{('want', 'you'): 5, ('want', 'i'): 430}, ('want', 'to'): 680},
 {('get', 'you'): 3, ('get', ‚i'): 68, ('get', 'to'): 409}, 
{('like', 'you'): 397, ('like', 'i'): 338}, ('like', 'to'): 345}]
So the the tuple with „you" on the first position in each dictionary, then with „i“ on the second position and so on?

Answer (score 0):

To get the final result you could use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
data = {('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'i'): 847, ('il', 'i'): 784, ('want', 'to'): 680, ('want', 'you'): 561,
        ('il', 'you'): 561, ('come', 'on'): 557, ('know', 't'): 499, ('go', 'to'): 447, ('right', 'all'): 440,
        ('want', 'i'): 430, ('know', 'don'): 410, ('get', 'to'): 409, ('like', 'you'): 397, ('like', 'i'): 338,
        ('get', 'you'): 336, ('il', 'be'): 330}


result = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    result.setdefault(k[0], []).append(v)

print([e for e in result.values()])
```

**Output**

```
[[561, 680, 430], [447], [397, 338], [440], [847, 1053, 499, 410], [336, 409], [784, 561, 330], [557]]
```

If for some reason you need the intermediate representation, you can do the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = {('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'i'): 847, ('il', 'i'): 784, ('want', 'to'): 680, ('want', 'you'): 561,
        ('il', 'you'): 561, ('come', 'on'): 557, ('know', 't'): 499, ('go', 'to'): 447, ('right', 'all'): 440,
        ('want', 'i'): 430, ('know', 'don'): 410, ('get', 'to'): 409, ('like', 'you'): 397, ('like', 'i'): 338,
        ('get', 'you'): 336, ('il', 'be'): 330}


result = [dict(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted(data.items()), key=lambda x: x[0][0])]    
    print(result)
```

**Output** (*intermediate representation*)

```
[{('come', 'on'): 557}, {('get', 'to'): 409, ('get', 'you'): 336}, {('go', 'to'): 447}, {('il', 'i'): 784, ('il', 'be'): 330, ('il', 'you'): 561}, {('know', 'i'): 847, ('know', 't'): 499, ('know', 'you'): 1053, ('know', 'don'): 410}, {('like', 'i'): 338, ('like', 'you'): 397}, {('right', 'all'): 440}, {('want', 'i'): 430, ('want', 'you'): 561, ('want', 'to'): 680}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!